# feols with step-wise fixed effects not working with custom formula

Tags: r, regression, fixest

I need to feed a custom formula to feols and have it estimate multiple models (various fixed effects), but this seems to break the `sw()` function. Compare:

```
library(fixest)
feols(mpg ~ disp | sw(gear, gear + carb), data = mtcars)
```

(That works.) This does not work:

```
feols(as.formula("mpg ~ disp") | sw(gear, gear + carb), data = mtcars)
```

Why? And how can I get that structure of formula input to work?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Sorry, edited.

Comment: "Why would it work?" would be a more appropriate question. In R you cannot edit formulas in that way. You very likely will find a solution in the section on formula manipulation of the fixest vignette: https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/fixest_walkthrough.html#formula-macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `paste` to paste the strings togeher

```
library(fixest)
feols(as.formula(paste("mpg ~ disp", "sw(gear, gear + carb)", 
     sep = "|")), data = mtcars)
```

-output

```
Standard-errors: Clustered (gear) 
Fixed-effects: gear
      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
disp -0.040774   0.015421 -2.64404  0.11821 
---
Fixed-effects: gear + carb
      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
disp -0.018388   0.016009 -1.14861  0.36955
```

which gives same as

```
> feols(mpg ~ disp | sw(gear, gear + carb), data = mtcars)
Standard-errors: Clustered (gear) 
Fixed-effects: gear
      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
disp -0.040774   0.015421 -2.64404  0.11821 
---
Fixed-effects: gear + carb
      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
disp -0.018388   0.016009 -1.14861  0.36955
```

NOTE: `paste` is more efficient compared to `reformulate`.  If it is a single expression, formula can be used an expression i.e.

```
fmla <- mpg ~ disp | sw(gear, gear + carb)
> feols(fmla, data = mtcars)
Standard-errors: Clustered (gear) 
Fixed-effects: gear
      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
disp -0.040774   0.015421 -2.64404  0.11821 
---
Fixed-effects: gear + carb
      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
disp -0.018388   0.016009 -1.14861  0.36955
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I marginally prefer [`reformulate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/delete.response.html) to `as.formula(paste())` syntax.

```r
fml <- reformulate(
    "disp | sw(gear, gear + carb)",
    response = "mpg"
)
feols(fml, data = mtcars)
```

From the [reformulate docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/delete.response.html):

> reformulate creates a formula from a character vector.

Although in this particular case the issue is simply that you cannot mix `as.formula()` into the same function call as a formula object. You could do this without `paste()` simply by including the whole term in `as.formula()`:

```r
feols(as.formula("mpg ~ disp | sw(gear, gear + carb)"), data = mtcars)
```

Output for both is:

```r
Standard-errors: Clustered (gear)
Fixed-effects: gear
      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
disp -0.040774   0.015421 -2.64404  0.11821 
---
Fixed-effects: gear + carb
      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
disp -0.018388   0.016009 -1.14861  0.36955
```